# How to add a digit to a string that is represented always using two characters?

Tags: swift

I want to align some digits and numbers (which will be Strings) one below of another:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I want every digit from 1-9 to have a space in front so then it will look like this - (10 should have the 0 digit below 9, and not 1 digit below 9):

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

In the second case it looks more like right aligned.
Is there a way in Swift to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String(format:)` with a field width of `2`:

```
for i in 1...10 {
    print(String(format: "%2d", i))
}
```

You can learn more about the [String Format Specifiers here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Answer (score 0):

1- give them all equal leading

2- make equal width constraint for all

3- right align labels from 1-9

Answer (score 0):

Apples [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) is what you want to use here.

```
let numbers:[NSNumber] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,100,1000]

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

for n in numbers {
    print(formatter.string(from: n))
}

// prints 01, 02, 03 etc.
```

edit:
Ah, I didn't read the question properly, you want a space instead of a 0. Nevermind this answer :)